# Submit button not doing anything from within a fancybox dialog in mvc 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, fancybox, forms, http-post

Currently, we have an edit user dialog (fancybox) that has a link which basically replaces this dialog with another fancybox dialog for changing a password. Everything seems to be behaving correctly until you click the submit button on the change password dialog. nothing happens at all. I checked fiddler and no request is being made. I check Firefox to verify that the change password controls are in fact wrapped in the correct form tags, and they are. What gives? I've looked through the net to find similar problems and there were some, but none were using MVC4 and I didn't quite understand them.

These fancybox modals are being loaded through a partial view. For instance, the link that opens the first dialog is simply a link where href="EditUserPartialAction". Works great. The model that is opened by the link from the first model does the same thing, it just has an href="ChangePasswordPartialAction". It loads up perfectly. Its just the button that doesn't do anything.

Here is the html being generated. You can see that the form looks right and should work (unless im overlooking something). And again, NOTHING is happening. No request is being made let alone an error. The cancel button works which just replaces this dialog with the previous edit user dialog.

```
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-ajax fancybox-opened" tabindex="-1" style="width: 533px; height: auto; position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 685px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible;">
    <div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;">
        <div class="fancybox-outer">
            <div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: auto; width: 503px; height: 279px;">
                <div id="modal-page">
                    <h1>Change Password</h1>
                    <form method="post" action="/AccountUser/ChangePassword?userId=0">
                        <div class="field_wrapper password">
                            <label for="NewPassword">NewPassword</label>
                            <input id="NewPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="NewPassword">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field_wrapper password">
                            <label for="ConfirmPassword">ConfirmPassword</label>
                            <input id="ConfirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="ConfirmPassword">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field_wrapper submit">
                            <a class="close_modal gradient change-password" href="/AccountUser/EditUserPartial?userId=0">Cancel</a>
                            <input class="gradient" type="submit" value="Change" name="update"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <a class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" title="Close"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
There truly isn't any real added jquery/javascript. Other than the fancybox library itself, this is all that is added which just hooks them up to a few classes:

// main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit, .addUser, .delete').fancybox({

        maxWidth : 486,
        autoSize : true,

    });
});
```

// plugins.js

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());

// Place any jQuery/helper plugins in here.
```

Comment: I don't suppose it's a result of your `<input>` tags not being closed is it? `<input />`

Comment: no, sorry. That got clipped out of the paste somehow

Comment: Shucks, that would've been an easy fix :P  I doubt it has anything to do with MVC if it's not even generating a request.  Is it possible the fancybox plugin is canceling the form submit?

Comment: I don't think so. Even if it did, I can't think of a reason why it would cause a problem here and nowhere else.

Comment: could you show your related javascript/jQuery? the bindings to the concerning selectors, etc

Comment: are you sure you don't have any `preventdefault` or `return false;` bound to the click event of that button?

Comment: I have not applied any javascript or jquery to the button at all! This is what is so confusing. I've been searching to see if maybe some other hook is grabbing the button but I can't find anything. These assets were provided by a 3rd party, but I don't see any custom code other than tagging certain classes with fancybox. This button isn't one of those, though.

Comment: @JFK There really isn't any added javascript here. But I updated the OP to show what little is added. It's really just some script that hooks up a few classes and another than supresses console errors for browsers that don't have a console.

Comment: Have you checked js console for any message?

Comment: There are no errors and no requests being made as a result of pressing the button. The only thing I can think of is that there is some javascript hook somewhere in the code that is blocking the button and I, for the life of me, cannot find it. In the meanwhile, I'm going to remove the form, change the submit button to a regular buttong and handle the post via ajax. A sour defeat.